# Angular 6/7, ngIf within ngFor

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to display a set of data in angular. the data is in key value form . I am using *ngFor for iteration.
problem is the value part is not uniform in all records. In some records, it is a string, in some records it is an array. So in those cases it is showing [Object object] in my page.

How I can iterate thru this inner array within value field, with *ngIf, that is my question.

part of code

```
<div class="row" *ngFor='let item of model'>
<div class="col-md-4">{{item.key}}</div>
<div class="col-md-8 " data-toggle="collapse" >{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

[image: screen shot]
I want to know how to use another *ngFor within *ngIf, and what condition should the *ngIf should have.

Comment: if value is object or array what we have to display? As key value pair or whole object as json string?

Comment: Can you post your actual JSON file data?

Answer (score 1):

Have a function in your component which checks the value and tells whether it is a string or an Array.

```
checkValue(val) {
    return val instanceof Array;
}

<div class="row" *ngFor='let item of model'>
    <div class="col-md-4">{{item.key}}</div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="checkValue(item.value) else stringValue">
        <span class="col-md-8 " *ngFor='let subItem of item.value' data-toggle="collapse" >{{subItem}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #stringValue>
   <div class="col-md-8 " data-toggle="collapse" >{{item.value}}</div>
</ng-template?
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

#### app.component.ts

```
.
.
.
 model = [
    {
      key: 'ContextNameSpaces',
      value: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }]
    },
    {
      key: 'ContextNameSpaces',
      value: 1
    }
  ];

  isObject(val) {
    return typeof val === 'object';
  }

.
.
.
```

#### app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of model">
  {{item.key}}
  <ng-container *ngIf="isObject(item.value); else elseTemplate">
    <span *ngFor="let j of item.value">
      {{j.a}}
    </span>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseTemplate>
    {{item.value}}
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try these:

Objects:

```
object = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": "test1",
  "name": ["abc", "pqr"]

},
{
  "id": 2,
  "test": "test2",
  "name": ["abc2", "pqr2"]

},
{
  "id": 3,
  "test": "test3",
  "name": ["abc3", "pqr3"]

},
{
  "id": 4,
  "test": "test4",
  "name": ["abc4", "pqr4"]
}];
```

For code :

```
ngOnInit() {
  for (let item of this.object) {
    for (let i in item) {
      if (typeof (item[i]) === 'object') {
        item[i].forEach((e: any) => {
          console.log("runseprate", e)
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi digvijay, perhaps your code is syntactically wrong. i is declared as an object of item type. then its used as in index. This is wrong code boss

Comment: Hello santubanglore i run these code in my VS code editor it will run fine no error...first forloop is for item in Object and second forloop is nested forloop which also represent the item inside item.. Then there is no matter of index... You can run these it will give you every item in Object

Comment: Hi digvijay, that is because maybe your data is defined as uniform array type. my data is exactly opposite. some are arrays, some are strings. That is why i am finding it quite challenging.